# $\{x:\text{$x$ is a set and } x\notin x\}=\{x:\text{$x$ is a set and } x=x\}(\text{the collection of all sets})$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the G$\ddot{\text{o}}$del-Bernays form of axiomatix set theory,
$\{x:\text{$x$ is a set and } x\notin x\}=\{x:\text{$x$ is a set and } x=x\}(\text{the collection of all sets})$?

Before axiom of regularity is introduced, we only know $\{x:\text{$x$ is a set and } x\notin x\}$ is a proper class and after the axiom is introduced, we know $\{x:\text{$x$ is a set and } x\notin x\}=\{x:\text{$x$ is a set and } x=x\}(\text{the collection of all sets})$.

I was wondering if this is a correct reasoning.

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct to me.

Comment: Yes. If the other axioms are consistent then they cannot prove nor disprove Regularity (a.k.a. Foundation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a correct reasoning, since extensionality also works for classes.